# Download text/csv content as huge file from server in Angular

Tags: angularjs, playframework-2.0, chunks

I have a backend server in play framework, which returns huge text/csv file in chunks.
How can I receive the file in angular in order to be able save the file in the client.

In regular file download I can use the following solution:

```
$http.post('/exportFile', reqData).
            success(function(data, status, headers, config){
                var pom = document.createElement('a');
                pom.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(data));
                pom.setAttribute('download', "file.csv");
                pom.click();
            }).
            error(function(data, status, headers, config){
                alert(data);
            });
```

But how to handle chunks?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

A few thoughts -

By default angular and underlying http stack will abstract "chunks" from you into a single success/failure callback. If you really want to chunk data, you might want a different URL scheme to page the results (and then issue a series of requests), or a web-push method like websockets (where the server pushes each bit). Maybe I'm missing something, but have you tried issuing another request within angular after the /exportFile request is done?

```
$http.post('/exportFile', reqData).success(function(...){
  // create url to where file.csv is, say fileURL
  var fileUrl = encodeURIComponent(data);
  $http.get(fileUrl).success(function(data...) {
    // data is now the contents of file.csv.
    fileContents = data;
  });
}
```

CSV files are probably easily compressed, maybe you're already doing that though.

Lastly the recommended MVC pattern with angular is to build elements within a directive and leverage two-way binding. You can also click a link on the element if you want to trigger the download immediately within a directive after it appears via:

```
$timeout(function() {
  angular.element(directiveElement).triggerHandler('click');
}, 0);
```

Okay, hope that helps

Comment: so basically you say if the server returns the file in chunks, it can be received in the front end using regular $http.success handler?
There no need to handle the chunks?

Comment: another though, when writing chunks, why i do not see several responses per write method?

public static Result index() {
// Prepare a chunked text stream
  Chunks<String> chunks = new StringChunks() {
    
    // Called when the stream is ready
    public void onReady(Chunks.Out<String> out) {
 out.write("kiki");
  out.write("foo");
  out.write("bar");
  out.close();
    }
    
  };
  
  // Serves this stream with 200 OK
  return ok(chunks);
}

Comment: I don't think you're going to get incremental access to the file in the client as 1-to-1 with each .write() call. Chunked responses are simply not well supported since comet/websockets/sse have more taken their place for streaming. Anyway, you can also play with XHR directly to try and get each chunk individually, e.g. var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
    xhr.open("POST", "/exportFile", true)
    xhr.onprogress = function () {
      console.log("onProgress" + xhr.responseText)
}